# is there a possibility to get sharepoint data extraction

Tags: database, api, sharepoint

I'm working on sharepoint on premise. I can't find the created lists and data . I need to get events from the sharepoint calendar but I can't find the path of that table. 
I use sql server

Comment: Hello Marwa, please do use English language on this forum. Concerning SharePoint you will find a special interest subforum here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Use Site contents to find your list and calendar

Answer (score 1):

You should not query data against SharePoint database directly.

To get SharePoint list data, you could use SSIS package for this.

[image]

Some threads for your reference.

https://dataqueen.unlimitedviz.com/2011/06/how-to-use-a-sharepoint-list-as-a-data-source-in-your-ssis-package/

http://www.axioworks.com/2015/01/using-ssis-to-export-lists-from-sharepoint-to-sql-server-an-alternative-approach/